# Convert Quaternion rotation to another coordinate system that is defined by direction vectors

Tags: vector, rotation, quaternions, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have 3 vectors representing the direction of each axis of the new space. I have a quaternion that represents a rotation in this space. I want to convert this rotation to global space. How may I do that?